# Snowflake: SQL Query to identify all the different users with the same ID from the same or multiple tables

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

There are two tables with both IDs and Usernames. Looking for a snowflake SQL query that results in identifying the IDs shared by different users from the same table or both tables.

**Table 1**

| ID | User |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | A |
| 1002 | B |
| 1003 | C |
| 1002 | D |
| 1005 | E |

**Table 2**

| ID | User |
| --- | --- |
| 1006 | H |
| 1005 | E |
| 1003 | G |
| 1002 | F |
| 1001 | A |

**Expected Results:**
1002 - [B,D,F] -> The ID 1002 is used by 3 different users across the two tables
1003 - [C,G] -> The ID 1003 is used by 2 different users across the two tables

**Note:** 1001 is not included because it's the same user from both tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `QUALIFY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT Id, User
     FROM Table1
     UNION
     SELECT Id, User
     FROM Table2) sub
QUALIFY COUNT(User) OVER(PARTITION BY Id) > 1
```

Comment: I would prefer to use `UNION` only instead of `UNION ALL` as it will automatically delete the duplicate records.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai A good idea, let the UNION to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

> query that results in identifying the IDs shared by different users from the same table or both tables.

This sounds like aggregation to me:

```
select id
from ((select id, user from table1) union all
      (select id, user from table2)
     ) t12
group by id
having min(user) <> max(user);
```